# Aligning columns on HTML tables

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm having to build out tables that have parent / child relationships. Here is an example.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Fruit: Apple
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Taste: Very sweet and Delicious
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="5">
      Shape: Round
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 01
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3423
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 02
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3424
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Fruit: Orange
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Taste: Sweet and acidic
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="5">
      Shape: Round
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 01
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3423
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 02
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3424
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Orange 1</td>
    <td>Orange 2</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Orange 1</td>
    <td>Orange 2</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you view this you can see that the "Amount" column is pushed way over because the "Taste" header is long and pushes it over. Is there a way to make the lowest level headers (Type,Amount    ,Color,Other,Other2) evenly spaced out? Or is there a better way to represent parent/child records with HTML tables?

Solution

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Fruit: Apple
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Taste: Very sweet and Delicious
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="5">
      Shape: Round
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 01
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3423
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 02
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3424
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
   <colgroup>
    <col span="1" style="width: 10%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
    <col span="3" style="width: 10%;">
  </colgroup>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Fruit: Orange
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Taste: Sweet and acidic
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="5">
      Shape: Round
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 01
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3423
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 02
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3424
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Orange 1</td>
    <td>Orange 2</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Orange 1</td>
    <td>Orange 2</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
   <colgroup>
    <col span="1" style="width: 10%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
    <col span="3" style="width: 10%;">
  </colgroup>
</table>
```

Comment: The solution was posted, then deleted by a user. Not sure why. The use of <colgroup> along with <col span="1" style="width: 10%;"> for the number of columns fixed it. I will update my code snipped with the full solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the rows that represent your logical subtable into an actual `table` and make sure that it's inside a `td` of the main `table` with the proper colspans being applied. I have applied the idea for your first "subtable" row and you can apply it for the others. In our example, **Type** is still wide, but the reason for that is that it has longer content. You can apply whatever styling you prefer. The subtables further down were not changed, you will need to apply this idea for them too.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Fruit: Apple
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Taste: Very sweet and Delicious
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="5">
      Shape: Round
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 01
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3423
    </th>
  </tr>
  <!-- START -->
  <tr><td></td><td colspan="7"><table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  </table></td></tr>
  <!-- END -->
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 02
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3424
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Fruit: Orange
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Taste: Sweet and acidic
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="5">
      Shape: Round
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 01
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3423
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 02
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3424
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Orange 1</td>
    <td>Orange 2</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Orange 1</td>
    <td>Orange 2</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Recipe:

You have `<tr><!-- your subtable here --></tr>`

I converted it to

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="7">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <!-- your subtable here -->
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you were looking for this! Change `colspan="1"` to `colspan="2"` for "Taste".

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Fruit: Apple
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="2">
      Taste: Very sweet and Delicious
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="5">
      Shape: Round
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 01
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3423
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 02
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3424
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Fruit: Orange
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="2">
      Taste: Sweet and acidic
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="5">
      Shape: Round
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 01
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3423
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 02
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3424
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Orange 1</td>
    <td>Orange 2</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Orange 1</td>
    <td>Orange 2</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Fruit: Apple
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Taste: Very sweet and Delicious
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="5">
      Shape: Round
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 01
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3423
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 02
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3424
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Fruit: Orange
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="1">
      Taste: Sweet and acidic
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:#ddd;" colspan="5">
      Shape: Round
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 01
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3423
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Granny Smith</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Fuji</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Batch 02
    </th>
    <th colspan="1" style="padding-left:60px;background-color:#eee;">
      Code: #3424
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="1">Type</th>
    <th colspan="1">Amount</th>
    <th colspan="1">Color</th>
    <th colspan="1">Other</th>
    <th colspan="3">Other2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Orange 1</td>
    <td>Orange 2</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td th colspan="1"></td>
    <td>Orange 1</td>
    <td>Orange 2</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>other info</td>
    <td>other info2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).